# Robust reconstruction of Indoor Scenes

Tags: scene, robust

I am very interested at this paper [Robust reconstruction of Indoor Scenes(2015CVPR)](http://redwood-data.org/indoor/tutorial.html), but I cannot run this project provided by the author. I have already sent a email to the author, but no response. Did any one run it once. There is a problem about "cannot share lib". I really don't know if it is my fault or just his.
Hope for your answer!!
Thx!!

Comment: Please mention the software project you tried to run, what actions/command you used to run and the exact error message

Comment: this is the link page: http://redwood-data.org/indoor/tutorial.html.  because my level on stack overflow I have no right to upload a picture. And the main error message is about "cannot share dll" and "cannot open depth source "